# Parameters error: ValueError: 'params' arg (<class 'list'>) can be only a tuple or a dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, database, discord.py, pymssql

I am trying to insert some discord bot data to a database. I did the Parameters Method but it doesn't work. I am new to dealing with MYSQL with python.

My Code

```
@bot.event
#Edit Log
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    MemberId = before.author.id
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480526097331650590'), 'The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``' % (MemberId) + before.content + '`` to `` ' + after.content + ' `` ')


    #Connection to sql
    conn = pymssql.connect(server='HAMOOOOD25\DISCORDPY', user='sa', password='31045', database='ChatLogs')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    #Declaring vars
    BeforeId = before.id
    BAuthId = before.author.id
    BAuthN = before.author.id
    Befcon = before.content
    Aftcon = after.content

    sql = "INSERT INTO Editedmsg VALUES (Message_ID, Message_Author_ID, Message_Owner_Name, Previous_Message, After_Message)"
    cursor.execute(sql, [(before.id), (before.author.id,), (before.author.id), (before.content), (after.content)])
    conn.close()
```

My error

```
ValueError: 'params' arg (<class 'list'>) can be only a tuple or a dictionary.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the error message suggests you to use a `tuple` instead of a `list`
in your [`cursor.execute`](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#cusor-object-methods) call. Besides that, your `sql` query is not properly formed (see [examples](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#basic-features-strict-db-api-compliance) section). Your `execute` call should rather look like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Editedmsg VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %s, %s)"
params = (before.id, before.author.id, before.author.id, 
          before.content, after.content)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: @HaMoOoOd25, I have no idea. You should include your full error message

Comment: (207, b"Invalid column name 'MessageID'.

Comment: Are you sure you get it inside `on_message_edit`? Do you have a full traceback, not just the last line?

Comment: I am sure that its there because I only used it inside `on_message_edit`

Comment: If you are giving just a single variable do not put it in paranthesis, put in square brackets. So;
params = [singleVar]

Comment: @MichaelC, in that case use a singleton tuple: `(singleVar, )`